# Symfony Prod mode No route found for "GET"

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a custum error404 page for my symfony app.
I have created the file in:

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig
```

Cleared cache, and I still get the 404 symfony dev page

```
No route found for "GET /ss"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »
```

AppKernel.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new Garcinia\SiteBundle\GarciniaSiteBundle(),
    );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}

public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
```

}

web/app.php

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
```

Comment: You get the dev page under prod mod ? oO

Comment: The Cookbook contains a page about error pages: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html :-)

Comment: The dev page will show no matter what in `app_dev.php`. Are you sure you're working with the `prod` environment? Did you make sure to do `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`? Specifically `--env=prod`

Comment: I have already run this commande, please have a look at my thread, I have added somes files

Comment: Hi @akrramokhan, you should try `app/console route:debug` to find proper route, if you found than remove cache manually and dump assests.

Comment: How are you serving the page? Are you sure your request is being handled by app.php and not app_dev.php?